# Image Magick Java Support

Tags: java, imagemagick, jmagick

Most of the time I get **ImageInfo() init<>** exception when I use Jmagick API. Does any one have an idea on the same. Does it happen generally or something needs to be resolved on the Image Info class? or there is any mistake on my side. Help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Code, please. And complete exception stack trace.

Comment: can you show more details

Answer (score 0):

This is my code snippet:

**//Jmgick.java**

```
File file = new File(filename);
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(file.toString());
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info);

image.setFileName(filename);


byte[] page;
int i = 1;
ByteArrayInputStream bais;


while( (page = (byte[])pages.get(String.valueOf(i))) != null ) {
    try {
        //read each page
        bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(page);
        //bais.read(image.imageToBlob(info));

        int a = bais.read();
        image.setDispose(a);
        image.writeImage(info);
```

**//GetDocServlet**

```
        JmagickImage ic;
        ic = new JmagickImage();
        ic.createImage(finalImagePath, pages);
        ic = null;
```

**//Exception**

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: magick.ImageInfo.init()V
at magick.ImageInfo.init(Native Method)
at magick.ImageInfo.<init>(ImageInfo.java:33)
at com.flagstar.idm.services.Jmgick.createImage(Jmgick.java:15)
at com.flagstar.idm.services.GetDocumentContent.assembleAndRespond(GetDocumentContent.java:186)
at com.flagstar.idm.services.GetDocumentContent.service(GetDocumentContent.java:69)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic : Is it possible for a solution here?

Comment: @montells : Is it possible for a solution here?